# Sync horizontal scrolling text with vertical when moving object

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I'm trying to make my text scroll from right to left with jQuery but with the vertical scroll bar, can you help me? When I try my code it works but it also makes the object move horizontally

```js
var $sun = $('.sun');
var $win = $(window);

$win.on('scroll', function() {
  var top = $win.scrollTop();
  $sun.css("transform", `translateX(${top}px)`);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 1277px;
  height: 148px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sun {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 75vw 0vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="sun">test</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The content is moving horizontally because you use `translateX()`. I assume in the question you instead mean that the content is moving *vertically* and you don't want it to.

In that case you can use `position: fixed` on the `.sun` element so that it's positioned relative to the window, not the document, and then the `translateX()` logic will move it horizontally as the page scrolls down. Try this:

```js
var $sun = $('.sun');
var $win = $(window);

$win.on('scroll', function() {
  var top = $win.scrollTop();
  $sun.css("transform", `translateX(${top}px)`);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 1277px;
  height: 1148px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sun {
  display: block;
  width: 600px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 class="sun">test</h1>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```